# Postgres error: a column definition list is only allowed for functions returning "record"

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, plpgsql

```
public class DimensionStoneDaoHibernate extends HibernateDaoSupport implements DimensionStoneDao 
      {

    public Connection con = null;
    int i=0;

    public void setCon(Connection con) {
        this.con = getSession().connection(); 
    }

    public Connection getCon() {        

        setCon(con);        
        return con;
    } 
        public List getMineralByApplicationId(String appId) {
            List<String> mineral = new ArrayList<String>();

        PreparedStatement query =getCon().prepareStatement("select * from  multiple_mineral_report(?) as types(val1 varchar)",ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);      

                query.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(appId));               
                    ResultSet rs=query.executeQuery();

                    String value = new String();
                    i = 0;
                    while(rs.next()){               
                        value = rs.getString(1);
                        mineral.add(value);
                    }

        } 

}
```

Above the SQL function `multiple_mineral_report(?)` returns string. When the above code is executed the following exception is thrown:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: a column definition list is only allowed for functions returning "record"

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION multiple_mineral_report(b integer)
  RETURNS character varying AS
$BODY$
declare
k varchar := '';    
sql_res record;
begin
 for sql_res in execute 'select  mineral_name from application_mineral as am inner join mineral as m on(am.mineral=m.mineral_id) where am.application_id = '||$1||'' loop
    k = k || sql_res.mineral_name || ', ';
 end loop;
 return k;
end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION multiple_mineral_report(integer) OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: SShould add more information : start with the language you use.

Comment: Ok i have Edited as per your request

Comment: Please show us the `create function` statement for `multiple_mineral_report`

Answer (score 2):

Your error is here:

```
PreparedStatement query =getCon().prepareStatement(
"select * from  multiple_mineral_report(?) as types(val1 varchar)"
,ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
```

You don't have to (and actually cannot) define the return type with a column definition list if it is well defined already. Your function is defined as

```
RETURNS character varying
```

Drop the bold part and this particular error should go away.
But really, since your function returns a single value, you want to call your function just like this:

```
SELECT multiple_mineral_report(?)
```